# If $\vec{w}$ is a vector such that $\vec{w}+(\vec{w}\times \vec{u})=\vec{v}$,then prove that $|(\vec{u}\times \vec{v}).\vec{w}|\leq\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: inequality, vectors

Let $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ be unit vectors.If $\vec{w}$ is a vector such that $\vec{w}+(\vec{w}\times \vec{u})=\vec{v}$,then prove that $|(\vec{u}\times \vec{v}).\vec{w}|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ and the equality holds if and only if $\vec{u}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{v}$.

---

I could not solve this question.I dont have any idea how to start with it.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Are these vectors specifically in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: This is not specified in the problem.

Comment: The cross product only works in $\Bbb R^3$, in all other cases the outer product of two vectors can not be identified again as a vector in the same space, thus $v=w+w×u$ would be impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use
$$
(u×v)·w = (w×u)·v = (v-w)·v\\
\text{ or } = (w×u)·(w+(w×u))=\|w×u\|^2
$$
Since $w$ and $w×u$ are orthogonal, one also gets 
$$
1=\|v\|^2=\|w\|^2+\|w×u\|^2=2\|w\|^2-(u·w)^2\\
\implies \|w×u\|^2=1-\|w\|^2=1-\frac12(1+(u·w)^2)=\frac12-\frac12(u·w)^2
$$